# SQL query with avg and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

I have some problems with writing a SQL query for MySQL. I have a table with the following structure:

```
mysql> select id, pass, val from data_r1 limit 10;
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| id         | pass         | val            |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| DA02959106 | 5.0000000000 |  44.4007000000 |
| 08A5969201 | 1.0000000000 | 182.4100000000 |
| 08A5969201 | 2.0000000000 | 138.7880000000 |
| DA02882103 | 5.0000000000 |  44.7265000000 |
| DA02959106 | 1.0000000000 | 186.1470000000 |
| DA02959106 | 2.0000000000 | 148.2660000000 |
| DA02959106 | 3.0000000000 | 111.9050000000 |
| DA02959106 | 4.0000000000 |  76.1485000000 |
| DA02959106 | 5.0000000000 |  44.4007000000 |
| DA02959106 | 4.0000000000 |  76.6485000000 |
```

I want to create a query that extracts the following information from the table:

```
id, AVG of 'val' for 'pass' = 1, AVG of 'val' for 'pass' = 2, etc
```

The result of the query should look like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id         | val_1   | val_2   | val_3   | val_4   | val_5   | val_6   | val_7   |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| DA02959106 | 186.147 | 148.266 | 111.905 | 76.3985 | 44.4007 | 0       | 0       |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

with more rows for each unique 'id', of course.

I already tried some queries like

```
SELECT id, pass, AVG(val) AS val_1 FROM data_r1 WHERE pass = 1 GROUP BY id;
```

This returns the correct result, but I have to expand it with results for the other possible values of 'pass' (up to 7)

I tried to use a nested SELECT within AVG but this didn't work because I didn't figure out how to correctly limit it to the current 'id'.

I then created Views to represent the result of each query for 'pass' = 1, 'pass' = 2, etc. But for most ids the highest value for 'pass' is 5. When using JOIN queries to get the final result from the views I received an empty result set, because some of the Views are empty / don't have values for a specific 'id'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `3` records with `pass = 5`, all with different ids. Which of these `id` do you want? Please post the output you would expect for the data you provided.

Comment: Does your AVG value have to be in columns or can your desired query return as many rows as many different pass values are there?

Comment: I edited my question and added a table how I expect my result. I have to feed the result on to another program, so there should be one id per row.

Comment: My edited query provide exactly the result you asked...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If I understand what you need, try this:

```
SELECT id, pass, AVG(val) AS val_1 
FROM data_r1 
GROUP BY id, pass;
```

Or, if you want just one row for every id, this:

```
SELECT d1.id,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 1) as val_1,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 2) as val_2,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 3) as val_3,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 4) as val_4,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 5) as val_5,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 6) as val_6,
    (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(d2.val), 4) ,0) FROM data_r1 d2 
     WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND pass = 7) as val_7
from data_r1 d1
GROUP BY d1.id
```

Comment: Marco, I just tried your solution and it seems like it does exactly what I wanted. Didn't knew that you could reference from an 'inner' SELECT to the outer one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

As I understand, you want the average value for each id at each pass. The solution is

```
SELECT id, pass, avg(value) FROM data_r1
GROUP BY id, pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

### I am assuming you have two tables with data similar to below:
DW

| id | sensor_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 300 |

### Sensors

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sensor1 |
| 2 | sensor2 |

And you want following result:

| ID | AVG_rows_sensor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 300 |

---

MySQL query to receive above results:

SELECT AVG(amount) AS AVG_rows_sensor
FROM DW
GROUP BY sensor_id;