# SQL - Retrieve Avg Score from Group

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My Database contains the following:

```
|    ID     |     UID      |     file    |    score    |    time   | 
     1    |     a827vgj28df |  jack_123  |      75     |       12:44 
     2    |     ayeskfkfjhk  | jack_999   |      5     |      12:12 
     3     |    b83759       | adam_123   |      7      |      12:12
```

Goal: 
I am trying to get a query that displays the avg scores for each file prefix (jack/adam)

To display like:

```
|  Key   |   AVG 
  jack       40 
  adam        7
```

Comment: and you tried which SQL statement?

Comment: @Randy The thing is, I do not know how to grab the filename prefix "Jack/Adam", without grabbing the whole file name

Comment: @TylerEsposito Including at least an attempt will help us with various info like the name of your table

Comment: Most SQL dialects contain functions that allow you to locate a character or string of characters in a string, and they also typically contain a function that allow you to take the left or right portions of a string value.  If you don't know about these, do a little research.  Or wait long enough, and perhaps someone will answer your un-researched question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query with avg and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702546/sql-query-with-avg-and-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the name prefixes. From there on, it's just a simple use of [`avg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg):

```
SELECT   SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '_', 1) AS key, AVG(score)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '_', 1)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like

```
select SUBSTRING(file, 1, 4) as Key, AVG(score)
from table
group by SUBSTRING(file, 1, 4)
```

You might get a better response in the future if you share what you've already tried.

Comment: This would only work if all the prefixes are exactly four characters long. In the sample data they are ("jack", "adam"), but I don't think this is really what the OP intended.

Comment: That is absolutely true. OP didn't specify, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the key using SUBSTRING_INDEX and  then group by

```
  SELECT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(file, '_', 1) AS key
      , avg(score) average
  from my_table  
  group by  key
```