# Simple SQL Average

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a select statements that outputs this:

```
[Total Days]
[991]
[127]
[664]
[889]
```

These values represent the total days each customer is registered. In this example I used 4 records, so to get the avarage I need to do *((991 + 127 + 664 + 889 ) / 4)*.

How to I achieve such thing in SQL?

Comment: most databases have the function for average like `AVG`.

Comment: Why your title is about `Count` if you are looking for `avg`?

Comment: Which database program are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query with avg and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702546/sql-query-with-avg-and-group-by)

Comment: Simply googling "sql average" would have given you your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(Total_Days) AS Total_Days_Average FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Don't you mean `AVG()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query,

```
SELECT (SUM(TOTAL_DAYS)/4) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```