# Select average price of per year

Tags: mysql, sql, dataset, aggregate, grouping

I have a dataset like this:

```
year, average_price
1993, 222.2220,
1993, 2333.333
1993, 333.345
1994, 3445.444
1994, 4493.33
1995, 66005.33
1995, 33994.333
1995, 33993.333,
1996, 33884.33
```

I need to show average price per year in this dataset.

Does this mean I can do sum of average_prices and just do group by year, something like this?

```
select year as y, sum(average_price) as avg_price from table group by y
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  If you want the average price, use `AVG()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query with avg and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702546/sql-query-with-avg-and-group-by)

Comment: @GordonLinoff The average_price column is acutally average price value for that entry I just need to show all average prices per year. Do I need sum of all average prices for that year, than group them by the year. I hope this is clear to you, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
select [year] as y, avg(average_price) as avg_price 
from Ttable 
group by [year];
```